# How to open another nodejs terminal from existing one

Tags: node.js, cmd

How to open another nodejs terminal from existing one, when an if condition is fulfilled..
I searched everywhere but can't find the answer.

So to make it more clear for example:

There is index1.js open and runs some commands, when an if condition is fulfilled it should open a new terminal , cd to another location and run the index2.js file in that location..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: "open a new terminal" is not clear: do you want a separate process, or a _real_ terminal (UI). If the latter on which OS are you running ?

Comment: new real terminal UI, in windows, but linux also

Comment: a "terminal" is totally different thing in different OSs. In windows it's `cmd.exe` IIRC while in Mac there are multiple different terminal tools (iTerm, Terminal, ...). And in Ubuntu you might want to run `gnome-terminal` and so on. Also, sending commands to these terminals (if possible) is probably done differently with different OSs. All that means that your question is too general, please focus it on a specific use case, also show us what you tried and where did you get stack. Writing a good question will help getting more traction!

Comment: new real terminal UI, in windows, but linux also, In fact I found how to open the terminal, but idk how to run a command in that new terminal, for example a nodemon index.js .. I am asking for nodejs terminal in fact, which is linux terminal, whatever OS you have..

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to run this index2.js in a child process:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 exec('node index2.js', function(error, stdout, stderr){
   console.log(stdout);
 });
```

Comment: Hi, its not working to me, even if I have in the index2.js in the same directory as index1.js. But as I requested, I need to open new terminal, change the location to the index2.js location, and then run index2.js  like : " nodemon index.js "

Comment: you can exec the terminal using the exec sending params: https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu